# Connecting to Oracle using VPN

Tags: oracle, vpn, lan, oracle-sqldeveloper

The Oracle server that I am connecting from (Oracle) SQL Developer 3.1.07 from windows 7 machine work fine when connected via LAN.
However when I connect via VPN SQL developer connection fails with following.

```
Oracle.javatools.db.DBException: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdevimpl.db.adapter.CADatabaseFactory.createConnectionImpl(CADatabaseFactory.java:66)
    at oracle.javatools.db.DatabaseFactory.createConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:534)
    at oracle.javatools.db.DatabaseFactory.createDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:208)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.db.DatabaseConnections.getDatabase(DatabaseConnections.java:607)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections$ConnectionInfo.getDatabase(Connections.java:156)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections.getConnection(Connections.java:1043)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections.getConnection(Connections.java:1024)
    at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.Worksheet$WorksheetController.testConnection(Worksheet.java:566)
    at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.Worksheet$WorksheetController.access$700(Worksheet.java:418)
    at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.Worksheet$WorksheetController$1.doWork(Worksheet.java:439)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTask.call(RaptorTask.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$RaptorFutureTask.run(RaptorTaskManager.java:515)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:419)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.db.adapter.AbstractConnectionCreator.getConnection(AbstractConnectionCreator.java:153)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.standalone.connection.RaptorConnectionCreator.getConnection(RaptorConnectionCreator.java:195)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.dialogs.conn.ConnectionPrompt.promptForPassword(ConnectionPrompt.java:67)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.db.adapter.DatabaseProvider.getConnection(DatabaseProvider.java:321)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.db.adapter.DatabaseProvider.getConnection(DatabaseProvider.java:254)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.db.adapter.CADatabaseFactory.createConnectionImpl(CADatabaseFactory.java:60)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:375)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:422)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:678)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:238)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1054)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:308)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:75)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:209)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:123)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:353)
    ... 34 more
```

What connection setting (VPN  or other ) are required to connect to Oracle via VPN ?

Answer (score 2):

I connect to Oracle via VPN several times a week without a problem.  (May be a different type of VPN connection of course)

Have you done any network troubleshooting?

- Do you have a hostname in your tnsnames.ora?  Can you ping this hostname?
- Can you ping the server on it's IP address?
- Do you definitely know that VPN connections are allowed access to the area of the LAN that the server is in?
- Do you know that your VPN/firewall allows you to access this area of the LAN on port 1521?

etc

:)